# Как запретить пересоздание Activity при разблокировке экрана?

Tags: android, java, activity

Есть программа, которая каждую секунду инкрементирует значение переменной, выводит его в `TextView` и издаёт звук:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
    int time=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }

    }

    public void start(View v){
        TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        myTimer = new Timer();
        final Handler uiHandler = new Handler();
        myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        time = time + 1;
                        txt.setText( String.valueOf(time));
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 1000, 10L * 100);
    }    
}
```

При блокировке экрана программа продолжает издавать звук, но при разблокировке `Activity` пересоздается, а в `TextView` пусто. Можно ли как-то запретить пересоздавать `Activity`?

Comment: Для начала, почитайте документацию. Начните с `onSaveInstanceState`.

Answer (score 1):

Значение переменной увеличивать в сервисе, к примеру, тогда она не обнулится.

А если без шуток, то [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) и [onRestoreInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) позволят вам сохранить и восстановить значение переменной при уничтожении Activity.

Comment: Сохраниться значение до блокировки экрана и, соответственно, все что будет прибавлено во время заблокированного экрана не будет учтено

Comment: @tpmanc при блокировке экрана можно сохранить в SharedPreferences значение переменной и запустить сервис, в сервисе обновлять переменную в SharedPreferences. Когда Activity снова запустится в onResume считать эту переменную.

Comment: Но это же довольно сложная реализация лёгкой задачи, согласитесь.

Comment: @SuperCreeper крутить поток, который будет счётчик наращивать, даже когда приложение свёрнуто, только в сервисе получится.

Comment: @Suvitruf, я бы сказал что в сервисе тоже не получится . система убивает сервисы так же как и приложения, но не так быстро).
приоритеты разные)) но все равно все зависит от конфигурации и от версии системы и от фазы луны тоже.

Здесь по человечески должен быть AlarmReceiver господа!!! и ничего не хронить в памяти - флушить на файло, сохронять в преференсы - да делать что угодно но не в памяти.

Answer (score 0):

У вас из-за Timer увеличение переменной будет идти не вечно, если что. Попробоуйте так:

```
Handler h = new Handler();
public void start(View v)
{
    TextView text = ...;
    h.post(update); //первый раз запускаем без задержки...
}

Runnable update = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        time++;
        text.setText("" + time);
        h.postDelayed(update, 1000); //а все последующие разы с задержкой в 1с
    }
};

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    h.removeCallbacks(update); //перестаём обновлять
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    h.post(update); //при возвращении снова обновляемся, если требуется
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: Почему не будет увеличиваться вечно, если не блокировать экран, то она увеличивается пока я не закрою приложение